# jquery caching elements once when run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious about if cachevar() will cache the el element once or everytime I run it?

```
function cachevar() {
    var el = $('.element')
    el.toggleClass('open') 
}
cachevar();
```

Comment: It wont cache anything. el variable will be allocated every time while cachevar method run.

Answer (score 2):

It will allocate a new variable every time you call it.

So it won't "cache" anything.

If you need to have a function that you plan to call many times and want to cache the elements it uses, you need to move those in a closure:

```
var el = $('.element');
function cachevar() {
    el.toggleClass('open') 
}
cachevar();
cachevar();
```

By doing so, `cachevar` will access to the same `el` object.

You can't cache objects without having them in a closure. If you don't want to have `el` clobbering your current scope, you can wrap that in a-so-called IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) so that it creates a new scope:

```
var cachevar = (function () {
    var el = $('.element');
    return function () {
        el.toggleClass('open') 
    }
}());
// el is undefined here
cachevar();
cachevar();
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to cache the element once in the same function ?

Comment: Is there really no option than to declare a var outside of the function cachevar() ?

Answer (score 0):

This will cache it everytime you call your function:

```
function cachevar() {
   var el = $('.element')
   el.toggleClass('open') 
}
cachevar();
```

so if you declare a global function then once you call your function then el will be cached to use anywhere then:

```
var el='';
function cachevar() {
   el = $('.element')
   el.toggleClass('open') 
}
cachevar();

alert(el); //<---here el is '$(".element")'
```